# Modify existing information about tied or equal values

Tags: sql

I am trying to work with an Olympic database where I am tasked with modifying the information I know about Olympians who have tied in the same event.

> "Firstly, extend the query to show more details about the event: in
>   place of the event id, display the event-gender, distance and style.
>   As part of this, the output is now to be sorted by event-gender,
>   distance, style. and then place.
>
> Secondly, show more details about each of the two competitors: in
>   place of each competitor number, display their given and family names
>   and the name of their country (not the country code)."

---

The four tables that I have to work with are:

Competitors, which contains: CompetitornNum, Givenname, Familyname.

Results, which contains: Eventid, CompetitorNum, Place.

Events, which contains: Eventid, Eventgender, Distance, Style

Countries, which contains: Countryname

```
Is my original query.

SELECT C1.EventID, C1.Place, C1.CompetitorNum, C2.CompetitorNum
FROM Results C1, Results C2
WHERE C1.Place = C2.Place
    and C1.EventID = C2.EventId
    and C1.CompetitorNum < C2.CompetitorNum
ORDER BY C1.EventID;
```

My problem is that I have a notion as to what I need to do, but the program we have been told to use crashes every time I try something out, I really dont know where to go from here.

```
SELECT Eventgender, Distance, Style, C1.Place, Givenname, Familyname, Countryname,     Givenname, Familyname, Countryname
FROM Results C1, Results C2
    natural join Competitors
    natural join Countries
    natural join Events
WHERE C1.Place = C2.Place
    and C1.EventId = C2.EventId
    and C1.CompetitorNum < C2.CompetitorNum
ORDER BY C1.EventID;
```

I am looking to select the Givenname, Familyname and Countryname of person 1, and person 2 instead of the CompetitorNum I am currently retrieving.

My new query finds the first person, but I am not sure how to change to obtain the seconds persons information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

I seem to have found a solution, however I am not sure if I am using the best method to accomplish the task. Is there a better way to do it?

```
SELECT C5.Eventgender, C5.Distance, C5.Style, C1.Place, C3.Givenname, 
C3.Familyname, C6.Countryname, C4.Givenname, C4.Familyname, C7.Countryname
FROM Results C1
    join Results C2 on C1.Place = C2.Place and C1.EventId = C2.Eventid 
        and C1.Competitornum < C2.Competitornum
    join Competitors C3 on C3.Competitornum = C1.Competitornum
    join Competitors C4 on C4.Competitornum = C2.Competitornum
    join Events C5 on C5.Eventid = C1.Eventid
    join Countries C6 on C6.Countrycode = C3.Countrycode
    join Countries C7 on C7.Countrycode = C4.Countrycode
ORDER BY C1.EventId;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: It is one provided by the university called SqlFire. I can provide you with the Program and Database if you require.

It is basically a no frills DBMS designed to take basic valid SQL display the output and tell us if it is selecting the right amount of columns. My second query selects the right amount of columns -- however it is the wrong output.

Comment: @Luckymee  . . .  Are you really allowed to use non-standard join syntax?  You should learn how to use standard join syntax, rather than the ",", which means cartesian product.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I was unaware what the manner in which I was writing the joins was syntactically incorrect. What would the correct syntax be as a matter of interest?
I'm not sure that is the issue but it would be nice to know.

Comment: Instead of using a WHERE clause, use an ON clause.  So:  `from Results r1 join Resuls r2 on r1.place = r2.place and r1.EventID = r2.EventId and r1.CompetitorNum < r2.CompetitorNum`.  Since this is homework, I assume it is related to a class of some sort.  You never need a "," int he FROM clause.  The proper syntax is some type of join.

Comment: @GordonLinoff as much as I agree with you about using the `JOIN` clause a minor nitpick: the join condition in the `WHERE` clause *is* SQL standard - albeit SQL89 standard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Ok that makes sense. I just had a play with that and was able to recreate my first query easily.
But I am still at a loss as to how to expand that to retrieve the information I require.

Comment: I still cannot get this question, it is becoming very frustrating.
Can anybody assist or point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT C5.Eventgender, C5.Distance, C5.Style, C1.Place, C3.Givenname, 
C3.Familyname, C6.Countryname, C4.Givenname, C4.Familyname, C7.Countryname
FROM Results C1
    INNER JOIN Results C2 on C1.Place = C2.Place and C1.EventId = C2.Eventid 
        and C1.Competitornum < C2.Competitornum
    INNER JOIN Competitors C3 on C3.Competitornum = C1.Competitornum
    INNER JOIN Competitors C4 on C4.Competitornum = C2.Competitornum
    INNER JOIN Events C5 on C5.Eventid = C1.Eventid
    INNER JOIN Countries C6 on C6.Countrycode = C3.Countrycode
    INNER JOIN Countries C7 on C7.Countrycode = C4.Countrycode
ORDER BY C1.EventId;
```